# Changing value of class variable

Tags: javascript, class, oop, object

I started OOP few days ago so i'm not experianced. I'm wondering is it any chance to change value of class property in order to affect on all objects, which use that class?

Example:

```
function Balloon(ID){
    this.ID = ID;
    this.speed = 1; 
}
```

Let's say I have 5 Balloon objects. And now i want to change all of their **speed** values to 2 without using for loop.

Comment: Those are not "class properties". They're **instance** properties, because they're set independently on each instance object.

Comment: Without iterating over the exact two balloons you're interested in, there's now way to achieve what you want. After all you need to know which of the two out of five balloons need to be changed in the first place. You can either change all 5 balloons using a class "member" (see Trogvar's answer) or you have to change them on a individual basis.

Comment: Please clarify for @Neal here, that you want to change speed value to 2 for ALL objects of class Balloon. As he has downvoted me for my answer. Thanks :)

Comment: @user1769428: Will you want to change the speed per instance basis?

Comment: From next time please make your question more meaningfull.. your question caused confusions :-) .. might aswell from next time adding pseudo code or pseudo output might help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `prototype` for that. Checkout the example below:

```
function Balloon(ID){
    this.ID = ID;
}

Balloon.prototype.speed = 1;

b1 = new Balloon(1);
b2 = new Balloon(10);

console.log(b1.speed); // outputs 1
Balloon.prototype.speed = 15;
console.log(b2.speed); // outputs 15, which is now also 15 for all other Balloon instances
```

Comment: Ahhh, but the OP only wants to change **2** of the balloons' speeds. **Not** all 5. (sorry but `-1` from me)

Comment: I think you misinterpret his statement. Reread it. This part `is it any chance to change value of class property in order to affect on all objects`.
And the `2` part in his comment is related to new speed value :)

Comment: I read it correctly as well. You're not keeping the context - he wants to change their **speed value on 2**. And if you pay attention to the beginning of his post, he wants to do it for **all** objects.

Comment: Thank you Trogvar I was waiting for that answer. Now every thing works fine.

Comment: @mkkrolik Welcome :) And if this answer suits you the best, don't forget to accept it

Answer (score 0):

Well you would need to edit the object's local **static** variables:

```
var Balloon = (function(){

    var speed = null;

    function Balloon(ID){
        this.ID = ID;
        speed = 1; 
    }

    return Balloon;

})();
```

The problem is that now **all** balloons would share the same speed! **AHH!** 
 That's not good at all... and in order to change the speed you would need to create a getter/setter for it... Which you really do not need in your case.

So -- to change **all** possible `Balloon` type object's speed at the same time, while allowing for each Balloon to *technically* have different speeds, the only conclusion is to go to each `Balloon` object and change the speed (sorry)

Comment: Ok fine, so i will use loop. Thank You!

Comment: I am happy to help @user1769428 :-D